# vscode cpp code formatter makes double Guillemet aligned like this >>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I am using vscode for cpp on Mac. When I declare a nested vector like `vector<vector<int>>`, this double Guillemet(>>) makes compile error, so I have to put a space between them. However, code formatting puts them back together! I want to know if there is any good solution like disabling the function of a code formatter.

Thank you.

Comment: What C++ standard are you using? I don't have this problem with the latest standards.

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>` is valid since C++11, so I guess you're using C++98. I would recommend just using C++11 or later if you can. If not, are you using an extension to do the formatting? You might be able to specify a C++ standard in the extension's settings

Comment: Thank you to both. @shananton I think you're right, come to think of it, the smart compiler accept my C++11 grammar with just a warning, even though I used C++98. I'll try in that way.